# How can I make Firefox remember an identifying element in addition to username/password?

Tags: firefox, password-management

A couple of sites I use have a username, second identifier, and a password.

One site ([ADP payroll)](https://secure.adppayroll.com.au/) has client id (company's number) user id (my ID) and password. My company's id is 5 or so digits that mean nothing to me. Since it is a number, I just type digits, and delete them until the form-filler remembers what I typed last, but it's not optimal.

The second site ([Australian Phone Company](https://pbx.australianphone.com.au/)) uses username, password and "account name". At least this time it is a string I can remember, but it's still annoying to have an extra field to fill in.

These additional fields aren't additional security, they are just user name space dividers.

Is there a way to get them auto-filled like the username/password fields are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox on its own doesn't do that, unfortunately -- the built-in password manager is very limited in scope.

I would strongly suggest you use a password manager *extension*, such as LastPass, Dashlane or KeePass. Personally, I use LastPass and it does a good job of that, although any decent password management service should be able to do what you want.

Should you choose to use Lastpass, the relevant feature can be found under **[LastPass Button]** > **Sites** > **Save all entered data**.

Comment: Just to add, whether it's Firefox or a password manager, it has to know what data to put where.  That becomes difficult if the web page doesn't externally identify some of the fields.  Online forms aren't always conducive to automatic filling.  In some cases, like password re-entry verification fields, the form purposely makes auto-filling difficult.  Also, if form filler software simply stores location or sequence, and the the web page changes, you can end up with data in the wrong place.